# Repeated requests to install google-chrome-stable

Tags: google-chrome

It seems that every time I log into my Kubuntu 14.04 system, I get a request to install google-chrome-stable, even though I've already installed it.  In fact, `apt-get install google-chrome-stable` tells me that I already have the latest version.  This is getting to be old news, even if it's just at the nuisance level.  How can I make it go away?

[image]

Comment: Is it a normal updates dialog or something else? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: It seems to be a normal update.  I'll attach a screenshot when it happens again.

Comment: OK, I have a screenshot now -- but how can I attach it to this post?

Comment: No, it doesn't look like a normal updates dialog. It looks like an attempt to install a local deb file, like you probably did the first time you installed Chrome. Why is it opening every time after logging in I don't know. Anyway, I would try to find and delete the Chrome installer.

Comment: I have a clue as to what's going on, but no idea as to what to do about it.  It seems that if I accept the "install package" prompt, then the installer replaces version 56.0.2924.87-1 by the older version 53.0.2785.143-1.  But I don't know why the installer is trying to do that.  Some configuration error, I assume.  But where?  I'm really not in a position to fix this bug, but a bug it is.

Comment: It surely is from a  local file. Have you tried searching for `google-chrome-stable`? If found delete it, you don't need it. Chrome is already installed along with Google's repository and is updated like the rest of the system.

Comment: There were a number of files related to google-chrome-stable, and I didn't know which ones to delete.  So I did a purge of google-chrome-stable, and indeed, chrome was gone.  I then reinstalled it using the deb package from the Chrome website.  Interesting -- that was version 54.0.2840.100-1, which is neither of the versions I'd seen previously.

Comment: OK. So now you can delete the deb you installed with, just in case.